# How to get all UICollectionViewCells to share the same height?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a UICollectionView where the Cell's do not fill their vertical space. What adjustment should I make to ensure each cell fills up the entire cell area? Or at least all share the same height for the row they are on?

[image]

Here is the Storyboard

[image]

**UICollectionViewFlowLayout**

```
class AddServiceFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    let cellsPerRow: Int
    
    init(cellsPerRow: Int, minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0, minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat = 0, sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRow
        super.init()
        
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing
        self.minimumLineSpacing = minimumLineSpacing
        self.sectionInset = sectionInset
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        let marginsAndInsets = sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.left + collectionView.safeAreaInsets.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.size.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }
    
    override func invalidationContext(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
        let context = super.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: newBounds) as! UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext
        context.invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics = newBounds.size != collectionView?.bounds.size
        return context
    }
    
}
```

**UICollectionViewCell**

```
class AddServiceViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvServiceName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tvQuantityNeeded: UILabel!
    
    public var onCellTapped: (() -> ())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.tvServiceName.text = nil
        self.tvQuantityNeeded.show()
    }
    
    public static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib.init(nibName: identifier, bundle: Bundle(for: ServiceLineItemCell.self))
    }
    
    public func configure(with service: TowService){
        self.tvServiceName.text = service.description
        
        if(service.calculated){
            self.tvQuantityNeeded.hide()
        }
    }
    
    public func eventTriggered()
    {
        onCellTapped?()
    }

}
```

**UIViewController**

```
class AddServiceViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private let columnLayout = AddServiceFlowLayout(
        cellsPerRow: 3,
        minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
        minimumLineSpacing: 10,
        sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    )
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Add Service"
        
        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout
        self.collectionView!.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
        self.collectionView!.register(AddServiceViewCell.nib().self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AddServiceViewCell.identifier)

        
    }

// removed for brevity ....

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension AddServiceViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allServices.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AddServiceViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! AddServiceViewCell
        cell.configure(with: allServices[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.onConfirmAdd(allServices[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the size of each cell using 'collectionView sizeForItemAt'?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a road map

1- You need to implement `sizeForItemAt`

2- Consider you have 3 columns per row , create a function that that accepts 3 Items ( introduced with the current `indexPath.item` ) from your model and manually calculate maximum height for each string in that model

3- Return the maximum height and by this you will set that height for all cells of same row